# Why the STL copy function in my case doesn't work?

Tags: c++, g++

When I write the code for exercise 3.1 In "essential c++", the STL copy function didn't work at all without any compiling errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input_file("input.txt");
    if (!input_file)
    {
        std::cerr<<"!! unable to open the necessary files.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> is(input_file);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> eof;

    std::vector<std::string> testStrVec = {"as","kg","mk"};
    std::vector<std::string> text;
    std::copy(testStrVec.begin(), testStrVec.end(), std::back_inserter(text));



    return 0;
}
```

When I debugging the program the text vector still be empty after the execution of copy function.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't actually went *over* the line copy call in the debugger? You can always check by printing right after the copy call. Copying seems fine and it should work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with GCC.

Comment: oh I tried to print the value after the copy function, turns out it works perfectly, maybe there is something wrong with my debugger